# how to call java method from actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, mxml

I've just now started working on Flex. May be its basic question but I’m not aware of it – how can I call a java method from actionscript. I want to call some java method on double click of a event. Can you please let me know how to proceed on this?

Comment: Do you mean call a JavaScript method via External Interface?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. no, I want to call a java class. basically that java method will call some other we service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flash Builder, under the *Data* menu, there are data service wizards:

[image: data-services]

These wizards auto-generate code and are convenient for connecting to WSDL:

[image: wsdl]

Or HTTP Services:

[image: http-service]

[Accessing data services overview](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/AccessingData/WSbde04e3d3e6474c46c45e7b4120d413dc14-8000.html) has example implementations, such as this example calling a restaurant web service with responder returning value objects from service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo"
               xmlns:employeesservice="services.employeesservice.*"
               xmlns:valueObjects="valueObjects.*">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:WebService id="RestaurantSvc"
                      wsdl="http://examples.adobe.com/flex3app/restaurant_ws/RestaurantWS.xml?wsdl" />
        <s:CallResponder id="getRestaurantsResult"
                         result="restaurants = getRestaurantsResult.lastResult as Restaurant" />
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;

            protected function b1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                getRestaurantsResult.token = RestaurantWS.getRestaurants();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Button id="b1"
              label="GetRestaurants"
              click="button_clickHandler(event)" />

</s:Application>
```

References:

- [Accessing data services overview](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/AccessingData/WSbde04e3d3e6474c46c45e7b4120d413dc14-8000.html)
- [Building data-centric applications with Flash Builder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/AccessingData/WSbde04e3d3e6474c4-668f02f4120d422cf08-7ffe.html)
- [Use the Data Services wizard to connect to a service](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining/exercises/ex2_09.html)

Comment: Can you also please let me know how can I call this http/SOAP service on double click event?

Comment: Example, and some references added.  There are numerous approaches to this both using these wizards as well as programmatic approaches.  Data services is a wide topic, but hopefully this demonstrates some options for you to choose in your implementation.